# No such property: betaDistributionApkFilePath for class: java.lang.String

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

I have found little glitch in **crashlytics/fabric** setup in gradle which took 2 hours of my poor life.

first of all i did everything they said in this guide:
https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

and here is the piece of code which everything caused:

**First try**

```
dependencies {
      ...

      compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;
      }
}
```

every library version in `dependencies{}` block iam using `ext{}` block in `appname/app/build.gradle` so in our case

```
ext {
    crashlytics = '2.9.4@aar'
}
```

so in the end it will be like this only change `implementation` which should be there in my opinion because it will be deprecated at end of 2018. `implementations` doenst change any behavior.

```
implementation("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$crashlytics"){
    transitive = true
}
```

but if u try to build this u gonna get:

```
No such property: betaDistributionApkFilePath for class: java.lang.String
```

wow. i have no idea why.. but lets investigate this. we will try different setup so forget everyting you saw above.

**Second try**

in our `appname/app/build.gradle` in `dependencies{}` change our lane to this so we have no `ext{}` for version

```
implementation("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$rootProject.ext.crashlytics") {
    transitive = true
}
```

and now in our root gradle `appname/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.fabric_gradle = '2.9.4@aar'

    repositories {
      ...
    }
    dependencies {
      ...
    }
}
```

Build is **OK** you can continue to work. But what? Its should be completely the same...

**Third try**

I dont know why but in our first try u just **CANT** in `appname/app/build.gradle` `ext{}` block name *crashlytics* variable it have to very everything else except **crashlytics** for instance **crashlytics_version** so lets make first try to working state.

```
ext {
    crashlytics_version = '2.9.4@aar'
}

implementation("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$crashlytics_version"){
    transitive = true
}
```

Build is **OK**. Magic.

or just do it in normal way and dont try to make smart things.... As first block of code in this long investigation which works also completely fine:

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') {
  transitive = true;
}
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Thanks for sharing this, I haven't seen this be an issue before, but I appreciate you sharing your answer as well. You may want to post that as the answer below.

Comment: What exactly should i post as an answer ?

Comment: Your third try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just **CANT** in `appname/app/build.gradle` `ext{}` block name your variable *crashlytics* it have to be everything else except **crashlytics** for instance **crashlytics_version** so:

```
ext {
    crashlytics_version = '2.9.4@aar'
}

implementation("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$crashlytics_version"){
    transitive = true
}
```

Build is **OK**.

or just do it in normal way:

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') {
  transitive = true;
}
```